# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as [the Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and was first solved by Euler.  His derivation (shown at above link) does some clever manipulations with the power series expansion of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

A more advanced proof uses Fourier transforms and [Parseval's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) for the function $f(x)=x$.

The link also gives a rigorous but elementary proof, requiring only trigonometric identities and binomial coefficients, together with the "pinching lemma", but no calculus.